# ¿Cómo acceder a los ficheros de un disco externo con una partición LVM2?

Tags: ubuntu, unix

He extraido un disco duro de 4 TB que estaba en un dispositivo que permitía conectarlo al router y acceder a su contenido por wifi, porque básicamente dejó de funcionar y quise aprovechar el disco duro.

El caso es que contiene información útil, atrapada en una partición LVM2 que he conseguido descubrir gracias a una versión Live de Ubuntu y gparted. Entonces he tratado de montarla siguiendo los siguientes pasos encontrados por internet:

```
sudo fdisk -lu
sudo pvscan
sudo vgscan
sudo vgchange -a y
sudo lvscan
sudo mount /dev/VOLUMEN_LOGICO/NOMBRE_VOL /mnt
```

En mi caso VOLUMEN_LOGICO = vg1 y NOMBRE_VOL = lv1

pero me da el siguiente error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error 

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

también he probado fsck:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck dev/vg1/lv1
fsck de util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-may-2015)
Data: recuperando el fichero de transacciones
Se pone la cantidad de nodos-i libres a 60374168 (era 60389623)
Se pone la cantidad de bloques libres a 6766840 (era 6782813)
Data: limpio, 401512/60775680 ficheros, 54197704/60964544 bloques
```

por último, a la desesperada, he pensado que quizá "Data" era el nombre adecuado en lugar de "lv1" y he probado el comando:

```
sudo mount dev/vg1/Data /mnt
```

con el siguiente resultado:

```
mount: special device /dev/vg1/Data does not exist
```

¿Hay alguna otra forma de salvar la información?
Si no, al menos de destruirlas todas y crear una sola normal legible por windows, para al menos salvar el disco duro.

**Más información:**

Salidas de "lsblock" y "lvdisplay":

[image: Ubuntu Live]

Salida de "dmesg | tail" :

[image: Ubuntu Live2]

**Actualización:**
Mejorando la precisión de una orden anterior,

```
dmesg | tail -1
```

me da como salida el último error:

```
EXT4-fs (dm-0): bad block size 65536
```

e investigando, he descubierto que es probable que al ser la partición demasiado grande, el sistema operativo no esté preparado para ello.
El caso es que me he descargado la versión desktop de Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS e incluso he probado una solución parecida a la que me propuso un usuario en una de las respuestas:

```
fuseext2 -o ro -o sync_read /dev/vg1/lv1 /mnt
```

pero me da un error en el montaje.
¿Hay algún truco diferente? ¿Me tengo que descargar otra versión?

Comment: Con el disco externo conectado cual es la salida de `lsblock` y de `lvdisplay`?

Comment: Ya las he añadido. Esos resultados me dan la impresión de que todo está en orden y se puede salvar, pero no doy con la tecla.

Comment: ¿Has probado el `dmesg | tail` que recomienda en el error?

Comment: Ya está añadido el resultado en el post. ¿Tamaño de bloque defectuoso...?

Comment: Quizas te pueda servir esto : https://kerneleros.com/solucion-a-mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member/

Comment: Gracias Nefefago, pero eso ya lo he probado antes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con el comando:

```
sudo fuseext2 -o ro -o allow_other /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1 /mnt
```

Y luego intenta copiar los archivos desde el terminal, ya que desde el explorador de archivos no sería posible.

Fuente: [I need help mounting an lvm2 partition with 14.04 LTS live USB](https://askubuntu.com/q/596835)

Comment: Gracias, pero me dice que no encuentra el comando "fuseext2". De todas formas, el sistema de archivos del volumen lógico es ext4, he probado por curiosidad "fuseext4" pero con el mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Has probado a instalarlo?
`sudo apt install fuseext2` 
Después vuelve a probar. fuseext2 ya lleva los módulos para ext2, ext3 y ext4, pero el comando sigue siendo el mismo.
Saludos.

Comment: He conseguido descargármelo y ejecutar la orden pero aunque parece que haya hecho algo, el resultado es el mismo. Aparece el volumen, pero cuando hago click para abrirlo, me dice que ha habido un error al montarlo, el de siempre.

Comment: Es lo que debe pasar. La única manera que tienes de copiar los archivos es utilizando el terminal, como te dije en la respuesta. Desde el explorador de archivos no podrás utilizarlo. Una vez hayas copiado los archivos a otro disco, formatéalo a ext4 y podrás reutilizarlo.

Comment: Pero ¿Como puedo copiar los archivos a otro disco si el original no está montado y además no puedo ver su contenido? He leido en tu fuente que el usuario que tenía el problema ha conseguido **montar el disco**, y de ese modo, salvar sus ficheros

Comment: ¿Me puedes pegar el resultado del comando anterior? (El del `fuseext2`). En principio, si se monta lo hace como cualquier otro disco. Sólo debes desplazarte hasta su raíz (probablemente en alguna carpeta debajo de `/mnt`) y allí usar el comando `cp -r origen/ destino/`.

Comment: Pues al final tenías razón: Desde la consola he podido acceder a /mnt y todos los ficheros del disco estaban ahí, y ahora toca copiarlos. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Quizas puedas probar:

- Verificar si `blkid /dev/vg1/lv1` como superusuario te da alguna pista del sistema de archivo en uso.
- Utilizar `gnome-disks` para verificar fácilmente si no es un disco con una partición cifrada (es una utilidad gráfica que tiene bastante inteligencia a la hora de detectar sistemas de archivo, si no esta instalada puedes obtenerla con `apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`). Si el disco estaba en un NAS, puede que el sistema de archivos sea `xfs`, y esta utilidad lo va reconocer.

  Si no llegaras a recuperar la información, esta misma utilidad te permite fácilmente borrar particiones, crear una nueva tabla y formatear de forma "compatible" con Windows.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, el sistema de ficheros de ese volumen lógico es Ext4. He usado la herramienta que me dices y me lo ha mostrado, pero cuando lo intento montar, a través de esta me da el siguiente error: `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.` No parece que haya ninguna información que indique en ese programa que la información esté cifrada.

Comment: Ok, sabemos que no esta cifrado, al menos no con LUKS o `dm-crypt` ya que lo reconocería inmediatamente. A la vez, no es problema con el superbloque, ya que `fsck` corrio correctamente. Lo único que se me ocurre, es intentar forzar el montaje. Prueba `sudo mount -o ro,noexec,noload /dev/mapper/vg1/lv1 /mnt/temp-mountpoint` (Tomado de [aqui](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/06/how-to-mount-a-broken-ext4-drive/), que a su vez viene de [aqui](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/06/14/digital-forensics-mounting-dirty-ext4-filesystems))

Comment: Pablo, he probado tu solución y me da el mismo error, pero gracias a tus fuentes, me he centrado en el error concreto que aparece escribiendo: `dmesg | tail -1` : `EXT4-fs (dm-0): bad block size 65536`  e investigando, he llegado a la conclusión de que probablemente sea un problema la enorme capacidad de la partición: 4 TB. Como he actualizado en el post, he probado otra solución, pero no funciona. ¿Conoces algún otro truco?

Comment: Revisando todo el hilo aquí, creo que la opción correcta es que te dio @zanwey más arriba. Cuando ejecutas `sudo fuseext2 ...` y no da error, entonces ya tienes acceso al disco, pero no se verá en la interface gráfica. Luego de montarlo, debes ir a /mnt usando el navegador de archivos, y deberías allí ver el contenido y poder copiarlo.

Comment: Si estas usando Ubuntu 16.04, el navegador o administrador de archivos Nautilus te permite ir a una directorio en particular presionando `CTRL-L` y luego escribir el camino (*path*) completo. Aqui deberías apretar `CTRL-L` y luego `/mnt/` y presionar `ENTER`. Alli deberías ver el contenido del disco y poder copiarlo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Pablo! Tenías razón, y aunque desde "Nautilus" no podía, desde la consola he podido acceder a los ficheros y copiarlos. Por justicia le he dado los 50 puntos a  Zanwey, pero tu te mereces otros 50.

Comment: Me alegro que haya funcionado!

Answer (score 1):

Hola encontré esto en [https://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition), espero sirva de ayuda:

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2   #This step may or may not be required.
sudo pvscan                 #Use this to verify your LVM partition(s) is/are detected.
sudo vgscan                 #Scans for LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo vgchange -ay           #Activates LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo lvscan                 #Scans for available Logical Volumes
sudo mount /dev/YourVolGroup00/YourLogVol00 /YourMountPoint
```